# Aggregate columns on a Dataframe grouping it according another dataframe without merging them

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes df1 and df2:

- df1 has column1, column2 and it has many rows(~10 millions)
- df2 has column2, a lot of other columns and it is short (~ 100 columns and ~ 1000 rows)

What I want to achieve is:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=column2).groupby(column1).agg($SomeAggregatingFunction)
```

But avoiding the merging operation since it will occupy a lot of memory.

There is any way to obtain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the memory overhead becomes a bottleneck, I expect this approach might be slower. Nevertheless, have you tried to subset `df2` based on the `column2` indexes that are returned after the `groupby` operation on `df1`? See below for an example of what I mean.

I suppose the other option would be to consider a map-reduce framework (e.g., pyspark)?

```
# two toy datasets
df1 = pd.DataFrame({i:np.random.choice(np.arange(10), size=20) for i in range(2)}).rename(columns={0:'col1',1:'col2'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({i:np.random.choice(np.arange(10), size=5) for i in range(2)}).rename(columns={0:'colOther',1:'col2'})

# make sure we don't use values of col2 that df2 doesn't contain
df1 = df1[df1['col2'].isin(df2['col2'])]

# for faster indexing and use of .loc
df2_col2_idx = df2.set_index('col2')

# iterate over the groups rather than merge
for i,group in df1.groupby('col1'):
    subset = df2_col2_idx.loc[group.col2,:]

    # some function on the subset here
    # note 'i' is the col1 index
    print(i,subset.colOther.mean())
```

---

**Update:** to include @max's comment suggestion to `apply` the function to the groups:

```
df1.groupby(column1).apply(lambda x: df2_col2_idx.loc[x[columns2],other_columns].agg($SomeAggregatingFunction))
```

Comment: Building upon your reply I have solved this way:

    df1.groupby(column1).apply(lambda x: df2_col2_idx.loc[x[columns2],other_columns].agg($SomeAggregatingFunction))